# Increment-related issue in Snakes and Ladders Algorithm (C)

Tags: function, increment

So, I have issues regarding the functions turns() and game(). Whenever I prompt the user to press "d" on their keyboards, the value of pspace (player's space) resets back to 0. Here's the code.

```
int turns()
{
    int diceval;
    int pspace = 0;

    diceval = diceroll(diceval);

    pspace = pspace + diceval;
    printf("Die: %d\n", diceval);
    printf("%d\n", pspace);

    return pspace;
}

char promptrolldie()
{
    char droll;
    int diceval;
    int pspace = 0;
    printf("Press D to roll the die \n");
    scanf("%s", &droll);
    if (droll == 'd' || droll == 'D');
    turns();

    promptrolldie();
    return droll;
}

/* Void Game is the game itself. Yes, the game itself, packed in one function. */
void game()
{
    int snake1;
    int snake2;
    int snake3;
    int plspace;
    int playlives = 3;
    int ladder1, ladder2, ladder3;
        
    snake1 = snakepositions(snake1);
    snake2 = snakepositions(snake2);
    snake3 = snakepositions(snake3);
    ladder1 = ladderpositions(ladder1);
    ladder2 = ladderpositions(ladder2);
    ladder3 = ladderpositions(ladder3);
    printf("Snakes are located at %d, %d and %d\n", snake1, snake2, snake3);
    printf("Ladders are located at %d, %d and %d\n", ladder1, ladder2, ladder3);

    promptrolldie();
    turns();
    
    plspace = turns(plspace);
    if (plspace == snake1 || plspace == snake2 || plspace == snake3)
    {
        playlives = playlives - 1;
        printf("You lost a life.\n");
        printf("Remaining lives = %d\n\n", playlives);
        plspace = (plspace - 3);
    } else if (plspace == ladder1 || plspace == ladder2 || plspace == ladder3)
    {
        plspace = plspace + 4;
    }
    if (playlives == 0)
    {
        printf("You ran out of lives.\n");
        printf("Game Over!");
    }
    if (plspace >= 50)
        printf("You win!");
    else
       printf("You landed on an empty block. \n");      
}
```

I have pasted my functions for rolling the dice (promptrolldie), the incrementing of the player's space (turns) and the game function where the turns function is called. Is there any solution to retain the previous pspace value?

Comment: Is this C? You seem to have a python background.

Comment: I took the liberty to buff up your indentation (assuming this is anything but python...). I suspect that it might actually answer your question. (especially check the effect-free `if`in `if (droll == 'd' || droll == 'D');
    turns();`) Please tag the language C or C++ or java or .... I also recommend to provide a [mre] to demonstrate your problem.

Comment: Please explain your plan of what the unterminated recursion inside `promptrolldie()` is supposed to achieve.